# When do the iOS autolayout interface constraints get executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In my view there seems to be a delay between `viewDidAppear` being called and the constraints of the interface elements being executed.

I have a `UILabel` whose size changes according to its content. If I check its constraints in `viewDidAppear`, they're empty. If I wait 500ms (for example) and then check again, the constraints are there as I expect them to be. The same goes for the bounds of the `UILabel`, no use immediately and then, once the constraints have kicked in, they're set as I would expect.

My code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Get constraints and bounds
    NSLog(@"description constraints a %@", [descriptionLabel constraints]);
    NSLog(@"description bounds a %@", NSStringFromCGRect([descriptionLabel bounds]));

    // Wait a bit, then get constraints
    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        NSLog(@"description constraints b %@", [descriptionLabel constraints]);
        NSLog(@"description bounds b %@", NSStringFromCGRect([descriptionLabel bounds]));
    });
}
```

And the output from that code:

```
10:39:35.949 Abc[2550:949660 constraints a (
)
10:39:35.950 Abc[2550:949660 bounds a {{0, 0}, {42, 21}}

10:39:36.480 Abc[2550:949660 constraints b (
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x175c0310 H:[UILabel:0x176d5080'elit ipsum amet ut cillum...'(290)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x175c0350 V:[UILabel:0x176d5080'elit ipsum amet ut cillum...'(629)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>"
)
10:39:36.482 Abc[2550:949660] description bounds b {{0, 0}, {290, 629}}
```

The `{42, 21}` are from Interface Builder and are arbitrary because the constraints then change the size to whatever the content demands.

I'm using Xcode 6.1, targeting iOS 7.1, running the app on an iPod Touch running iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

for view controllers and

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
```

after calling

```
[super layoutSubviews];
```

for views.